# Grouped category at drilldown 2nd level chart possible in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, highcharts

Is grouped category at 2nd level drill down possible?

I have gone through examples but all the charts shows grouped category in main chart.
I tried to edit my code to add grouped category at drilldown 2nd level chart but got errors.

Looking for response.

Comment: In other words, groupind cateories should display only on second drilldown level ?

Comment: Yes and 3rd level also

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible, so you can destroy and create new chart.